# Can manually triggered jobs of pipeline take user-input for paramters?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have two jobs (Job1 & Job2). Both are parameterized with the same parameters but the parameter values differ and are designed using the Active-Choice-Parameter (uno) plugin.

I wish to run both jobs in pipeline however, below is the exact requirement.

1. When the pipeline is executed Job1 executes and prompts user to enter parameters (UI). The user enters / selects the values and triggers it to build.
2. Once the build on Job1 completes the user is prompted for (approval) to proceed to the next Job2. The user approves by clicking "OK/Proceed" button; & thereby Job2 of the pipeline gets triggered.
   Note: I have achieved this using "input" feature of Groovy Script.
3. The parameter values of Job1 should be passed and should showup in Job2; however the user should be able to see and modify the passed values for any parameter in Job2 (UI).

Note: I'm able to pass the parameter values using "Parameterized Trigger Plugin" on "Post-Build-Actions" of Job1

## Problem statement:

Running the pipeline does not show users parameter screen (UI) for either Job1 or Job2 so that the user could enter / select and change the parameters for either Job1 or Job2 during the pipeline run.

## Note:

I'm able to overcome the Problem Statement by using Build Pipeline Plugin: 
But the reason i do not wish to consider this solutions is

1. I don't know how can I inject the groovy pipeline script input element which prompts for approval between jobs.
2. I have read that using the pipeline plugin has advantages over using Build Pipeline Plugin

Below is Groovy script (Pipeline script)

```
    agent any   //agent specifies where the pipeline will execute. 
    stages {
        stage ("build PROD") {  //an arbitrary stage name
            steps {
                build 'job1'    //this is where we specify which job to invoke.
            }
        }
        stage ("build DR") {            //an arbitrary stage name
            input{
                message "Press Ok to continue"
                submitter "user1,user2"
                parameters {
                    string(name:'username', defaultValue: 'user', description: 'Username of the user pressing Ok')
                    }
            }
            steps { 
                echo "User: ${username} said Ok."
                build 'job2'    //this is where we specify which job to invoke.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any solution would be of great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use the parameter https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters

Then you have the default user interface, which is simpler then you custom groovy code.

Comment: parameters is not the issue here. Getting the UI for user interaction for both the jobs along with the approval button is what is needed. Is it possible to put the URLs of both the jobs in pipeline (maybe that way I would get the UI for both) while passing parameters from job1 to job2  ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are keeping the jobs separate?  What I would do is re-evaluate your job flow and see if it makes more sense to have the jobs merge into one pipeline.

Comment: Both the jobs are different as one runs in production and only if successful will the deployment job work in the disaster recovery environment. Also, Active-Choice-Parameter (uno) plugin makes the parameter construction for both the jobs different. Hence, the jobs are separate.